# Qual a melhor prática de estilizar um Email body?

Tags: css, envio-de-email

Estou na fase de desenvolvimento de um email de boas vindas. Gostaria de saber qual a prática mais correta e utilizada de adicionar o style no meu email.

Minha dúvida é: devo utilizar CSS inline, incorporado ou externo?

Analisei que muitos sites usam a forma inline, mas estou preocupado com manutenção futuramente.

Comment: @Renan Sim, mas tipo como que é usado o CSS, inline, incorporado ou externo?

Comment: Gostaria de saber qual a melhor prática, mas não sei o porque ja negativaram a pergunta...

Comment: Muitos serviços de email não carregam folhas externas e incorporadas. Pode até utilizar, mas é por sua conta em risco.

Comment: @Renan Então vou estilizar inline mesmo, obrigado.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Usar CSS linkado é mais facil de alterares cores e background caso mantenha a mesma extrutura.

> CSS linkado é o modelo recomendado, pois neste modelo todo o código
>   CSS fica em um arquivo separado, podendo ser linkado a várias páginas
>   do site. Este é o melhor modelo para promover o reaproveitamento do
>   código.

**No entanto no caso do e-mail evite usar CSS externo.**

1. Alguns clientes de e-mail não aceitam. Tanto no HEAD, quanto no
   BODY.** Utilize CSS inline (direto no elemento), porém não abuse de
   propriedades como position, float e etc…
2. Todas as imagens devem ter display:block, assim evita que o Gmail e o Hotmail acrescentem um espaçamento entre elas.
3. **Não use** style=”color: #fff”; **Use** style=”color: #ffffff”;
4. CSS3 / HTML5: Apresentam uma taxa muito baixa de compatibilidade, de forma que não são recomendados.
5. Finalmente lembre-se de evitar o uso de divs se seu template tem várias colunas, neste caso, as tabelas são a ferramenta mais confiável.
6. Não deve fazer construir o seu template todo em imagens pois alguns programas de email bloqueiam a visualização dessas imagens.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[Fonte](https://tableless.com.br/boas-praticas-para-e-mail-marketing/)

Observe a seguinte tabela que mostra o que é mais aconselhado usar nos diversos clientes de e-mail

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Consulte ainda este [site](https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/) irá mostrar as tags que deve ou não usar nos diversos clientes de e-mail

Na página da google poderá ainda encontrar esta informação bastante útil sobre o funcionamento do [gmail](https://developers.google.com/gmail/design/)

Existem ferramentas que convertem o codigo CSS linkado em CSS inline dou o seguinte [exemplo](http://foundation.zurb.com/emails/inliner-v2.html)

Answer (score 10):

Veja este artigo https://tableless.com.br/email-marketing-testes-css-inliner-parte-2/.

Basicamente, ele diz que se você usar as tag `<style>...</style>` no header ou body do seu e-mail, os GMail da vida vão ignorá-los.

Ou seja, para que todos os mailclient possam apresentar seu e-mail corretamente, você deve usar o estilo incorporado à tag.