# É possível adicionar uma animação SVG ao corpo HTML de um email?

Tags: html, svg

Estou fazendo um algoritmo de envio de email para confirmação de conta, estou conseguindo enviar o email normalmente, contudo, gostaria de de adicionar uma animação SVG no corpo HTML do email. Estou utilizando outlook, mas também gostaria que esta animação podesse ser visualizada no gmail.

É possível ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não é possível, pois o Google não aceita SVG nos clientes de email como vc pode consultar aqui: https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/text-fonts/svg/

Aqui tem uma pergunta relacionada com mais detalhes de outras coisas que podem te interessar: [Código HTML no corpo do e-mail](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/273105/c%c3%b3digo-html-no-corpo-do-e-mail/)

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]