# Como enviar um "email Marketing" em ASP .NET?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, envio-de-email

**De início:**
Estou enviando um email utilizando o serviço padrão do ASP .NET conforme código abaixo

```
public class SendMail
{
    public bool SendEmail(MailModel mail, string subject, string body)
    {
        try
        {
            string emailRemetente = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["EmailRemetente"].ToString();
            string senhaRemetente = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SenhaRemetente"].ToString();

            MailMessage message = new MailMessage(emailRemetente, mail.To, subject, body);
            Console.WriteLine(message.IsBodyHtml);
            message.IsBodyHtml = true;
            message.BodyEncoding = UTF8Encoding.UTF8;

            SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com", 587);
            client.EnableSsl = true;
            client.Timeout = 100000;
            client.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
            client.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
            client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(emailRemetente, senhaRemetente);

            client.Send(message);

            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

onde o parâmetro MailModel estará preenchido como:

```
public class MailModel
{
    public string From { get; set; }
    public string To { get; set; }
}
```

1. Quero saber como envio email marketing(emails personalizados
   utilizando HTML), apenas adiciono uma referencia no body?
2. Existe algum framework ou plugin para ASP .NET que faça isso?

Comment: Não consegui entender qual é exatamente a sua dúvida

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você já tem tudo feito no seu código, não há necessidade de um framework para o envio.

Você setou `message.IsBodyHtml = true;` isso faz com que os servidores de email leia a sintaxe do seu email como HTML. Então basta criar um arquivo HTML e passa-lo para o método `SendEmail`(no parametro body).

```
string emailMarketing = File.ReadAllText("caminho_do_arquivo_html");
SendEmail(MailModel,subject,emailMarketing);
```

Só aconselho você a tomar cuidado com a semântica do seu HTML pois cada servidor de email (Gmail,Hotmail,Yahoo e etc) aceita ou não as tags HTML, você precisa criar um Email Marketing com um HTML que seja genérico e que vá funcionar na maioria dos servidores de email.

Eu fiz uma pergunta ["Qual a melhor prática de estilizar um email body"](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/215607/qual-a-melhor-pr%C3%A1tica-de-estilizar-um-email-body) e me ajudou muito pois os serviços de email estavam "excluindo" as tags que eles não aceitavam e meu HTML estava chegando todo desconfigurado, da uma lida nas respostas vai te ajudar muito !